# About hyphen and reflexive pronouns

Tags: punctuation, reflexive-pronouns

Please take a look at the following sentence from [this article](https://stancarey.wordpress.com/2009/02/24/how-to-use-quotation-marks/#ScareQuotes):

> Maybe the usage is colloquial, slang, technical, inaccurate, euphemistic, misleading or inappropriate, and the writer wants to distance **him- or herself** from it, or to suggest irony, scepticism, distaste or outright derision:

I would like to ask you two questions:

1. What is the purpose of the hanging hyphen right after him?
2. Why wasn't used himself?

As written, I could read that part as if the writer wanted to distance somebody else from it, not himself.

Please let me know your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This hyphen is a [suspended hyphen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen#Suspended_hyphens). It isn't mandatory and is mainly used to prevent redundancy. Because it is a matter of style, some people/style guides will recommend against using a suspended hyphen when the original words don't have hyphens (as is the case here).

You can rewrite it to remove the hyphen like this:

> Maybe the usage is colloquial, slang, technical, inaccurate, euphemistic, misleading or inappropriate, and the writer wants to distance **himself or herself** from it, or to suggest irony, scepticism, distaste or outright derision:

Comment: I appreciate your answer and I should have known that these are just simple guidelines, not hard-and-fast rules. Thanks so much! +1

Answer (score 1):

The author wanted to indicate that it could have been "himself" or "herself" without repeating the "self" part.  It probably would have been clearer to write **"himself or herself"**, though.

It definitely does not indicate that the writer wanted to distance somebody else from it, though.  Firstly, there's nobody else mentioned whom *him* could refer to.  Secondly, if the writer did want to distance somebody else, we wouldn't put a dash after *him*.